# Send different logs with rsyslog

Tags: rsyslog, qradar

I'm currently using rsyslog to send logs from a Linux server to QRadar (IBM's SIEM).
However, the server sends a lot of logs and I would like to filter them directly in the rsyslog.conf file. But if I write someting else than
`*.* @MyServerIp`
no logs are sent. Can anyone help me ?
Thank you !